# Writing a simple plugin/component

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, input, components

I want to write a component(or plugin) like that.
when i write: 
`var a = new myPluginName ('#myElement', { bla:bla});`

or

```
$('#myElement').myPluginName();
```

It must create two input. Thats all.
How can i do this? Can you give me an example like that? Or any idea will be helpful.

In other words, my goal is create two input with my component.
Thank you.

Comment: do you want your plugin to create two inputs , or to append them inside something, or create one input, and call it two times, you need to specify the problem.

Comment: i need to create two input with my plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom jQuery plugin like this:

```
(function($){
 $.fn.extend({ 
     //plugin name - inpuX
     inputX: function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            width: 200,
            defaultPadding: 2,
            border: '2px solid red'
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
              var o =options;
              var obj = $(this);                             

              $(obj)
                  .css('padding', o.defaultPadding)
                  .css('width', o.width)
                  .css('border', o.border)
                  .css('display', 'block');  
        });
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

and then call it like this:

```
 $('#inputA').inputX({width: 150, defaultPadding:5, border: '1px dashed black'});
 $('#inputB').inputX({width: 200, defaultPadding:10});
```

on elements in html:

```
<input id="inputA" type="text" />
<input id="inputB" type="text" />
```

Comment: Thats nice. But how can i create input with plugin?

Comment: Try to play with jquery and post your problems as new questions, one by one. Google a jquery plugin a bit. Have fun! ;-)